How to disable option to play video on React Player
I am viewing the react player in carousel with thumbnail view.
I want to disable the thumbnail from playing.
I am looking for a way to show the React Player just as a preview, so it won't be clickable to start playing. I am using light mode.
Is that possible?

Why do you want to embed a video player, if you don't want to play the video? Would it not make more sense if you simply showed an image then?

@CBroe because I will load the same thumbnail for both the main carousel and the thumb carousel, it will be more effective. And they'll have the same "preview" to make it clear it's a video from looking at the thumbnail
